# How to prevent foreign key lookup in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE master_id IS NULL
```

The `master` field is a ForeignKey, but in this case, I just need to know whether it is NULL or not so I don't need to do a foreign key lookup. However, if I do:

```
Catalog.objects.filter(master_id=None).values_list('is_tv', flat=True).count()
```

Here is the example statement it does:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `catalog` LEFT OUTER JOIN `main_titlemaster` 
    ON (`main_catalog`.`master_id` = `main_titlemaster`.`id`) 
    WHERE `main_titlemaster`.`id` IS NULL
```

How can I prevent this useless FK lookup without diving into raw SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`__isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull) lookup keyword.

```
Catalog.objects.filter(master__isnull=True).values_list('is_tv', flat=True).count()
```